# Cannot convert to integer from illuminate

Tags: php, laravel

I retrieve data:

```
$credit = DB::table('expert')
    ->where('use_id', $use_id)
    ->select('credit')
    ->get();

if ($count < $credit) {
    return response()->json(true);
}
```

However, it failed at the `$count < $credit`, error Object of class `Illuminate\Support\Collection` could not be converted to int, I tried putting `->first()`; got same thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`->get()` will return the collection.

`->first()` instead of `->get()` return the query builder stdClass of `expert` table.

So you need to call its attribute like this:

```php
$credit = DB::table('expert')
    ->where('use_id', $use_id)
    ->select('credit')
    ->first()->credit;
```

Comment: This can be work correctly and I upvoted, but `->first()` should return a `stdClass` object, not query builder, right?

Comment: @CalosKao yes. it a query builder's stdClass